# Who is the victimized Kree donor for Project T.A.H.I.T.I.?

Tags: marvel, marvel-cinematic-universe, agents-of-shield

Project T.A.H.I.T.I. is

> eventually revealed to be cannibalizing the body of a dead Kree, extracting its fluids from its decomposing corpse to create the GH-series of serums which served as the resurrection mechanism for Coulson.

Now, I’m not suggesting Fury or S.H.I.E.L.D. killed the Kree to do this, but it’s pretty morbid stuff in any case.

He just may have been the equivalent of a private who died in a crash on Earth, or whatever. His life or name while alive may have been inconsequential. But though his death, his life arguably contributed to one of the most consequential events of the MCU universe:

> Coulson’s resurrection from death after being killed in the first *Avengers* film. Who was he?

### What was this guy’s name?

Comment: I believe it's unknown but I'm not familiar enough with AoS to know if I'm missing anything to be confident in an answer.

Comment: Given that Coulson's resurrection has had no effect whatsoever on the MCU films or other TV shows, I would say "one of the most consequential events" is completely wrong.

Comment: Well, it’s at least arguable, though. I never claimed the argument would be a good one.

Comment: https://marvelcinematicuniverse.fandom.com/wiki/G.H.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

As per [Valorum's posted link](https://marvelcinematicuniverse.fandom.com/wiki/G.H.), the Kree "donor" is currently unidentified, and is only referred to as the "Guest Host", leading to the first characters of [GH.325](https://marvelcinematicuniverse.fandom.com/wiki/GH.325), the drug used in Project T.A.H.I.T.I..

Also, the "Guest Host" was left on Earth thousands of years ago, and was by all indications inactive during that time, it is unlikely to be any named Kree already mentioned in the show or MCU films.